Nuxt Pages takes a long time to load, if opened first time
I encountered a problem that the nuxt page takes a long time to load, if opened first time
It happens on all pages in the project, where i am using composables.
Example:
I have a login page, where I put all the functions in composables so that my Login's Page:
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: "custom",
  middleware: "login",
});

useHead({
  title: "Вход",
  meta: [
    {
      name: "description",
      content: "Вход",
    },
  ],
});

const { email, password, login } = useLogIn()
</script>

That's my useLogin composable:
export default function autorization() {
  const toast = useToast();
  const email = ref("");
  const password = ref("");
  const token = useToken();
  const {
    public: { apiBase },
  } = useRuntimeConfig();

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      if (email.value === "" || password.value === "") {
        toast.add({ title: "Заполните все поля", color: "yellow" });
        return;
      }

      const response = await $fetch(`${apiBase}/user/login`, {
        params: {
          login: email.value,
          password: password.value,
        },
      });
      
      if (response.isVerify) {
        token.value = `Bearer ${response.token}`;
        console.log("Logged in");
        navigateTo("/");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Ошибка при авторизации: ", error.response);
      try {
        if (error.response._data.message === "Неверный логин или пароль") {
          toast.add({ title: "Неверный логин или пароль", color: "red" });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        toast.add({ title: "Произошла какая-то ошибка", color: "red" });
      }
    }
  };

  return {
    email,
    password,
    login,
  };
}

In this screenshot, I can see a delay when I first time go on the page.

I also checked perfomance tab, when i put all the functions in Login page:
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: "custom",
  middleware: "login",
});

useHead({
  title: "Вход",
  meta: [
    {
      name: "description",
      content: "Вход",
    },
  ],
});

const toast = useToast();
const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const token = useToken();
const {
  public: { apiBase },
} = useRuntimeConfig();

const login = async () => {
  try {
    if (email.value === "" || password.value === "") {
      toast.add({ title: "Заполните все поля", color: "yellow" });
      return;
    }

    const response = await $fetch(`${apiBase}/user/login`, {
      params: {
        login: email.value,
        password: password.value,
      },
    });

    if (response.isVerify) {
      token.value = `Bearer ${response.token}`;
      console.log("Logged in");
      navigateTo("/");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Ошибка при авторизации: ", error.response);
    try {
      if (error.response._data.message === "Неверный логин или пароль") {
        toast.add({ title: "Неверный логин или пароль", color: "red" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.add({ title: "Произошла какая-то ошибка", color: "red" });
    }
  }
};

Here are the differences


Very interesting. I think that the best to move forward is to open an issue on the project itself, on Github. This one might be quite technical as to why exactly it is behaving like that. Considering sharing them a [repro] of such a use-case so that they could inspect it faster and more efficiently.
